# Tethered VPN on Macbook fails to connect, but standard VPN over WiFi works

Tags: cisco, mac-osx, cisco-asa, cisco-vpn, ipad

I have a MacBook using the Cisco client and it works fine except when I use the special Mac/iPad ability to tether over the iPad data connection.

For those that are unfamiliar with this, the Mac and iPad can tether over Bluetooth to leverage the iPad's internet connection.

I'm not the network administrator of the Cisco VPN target, but I want to give them the most accurate/relevant information to fix this.

How do I troubleshoot/collect information to make our network admin's life easier?

Comment: I seem to begin to vaguely conclude that the above is not the way to do it, but am I right?

Comment: @KonradGajewski shouldn't be any different than using a cellular card on a laptop, but with Apple-Apple devices, this is the preferred and only way to tether a data plan to a Mac